# Reset Password now sending reset instructions

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, mailgun

Cannot send mail to reset user password!
here is my index.js file

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    verifyUserEmails: false,  //depends on your needs, you can set it to false 
    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)
    preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false, // defaults to false
    publicServerURL: 'https://a.herokuapp.com/parse',
    // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
    appName: 'App',
// The email adapter
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
            // The address that your emails come from
            fromAddress: 'a@a.com',
            // Your domain from mailgun.com
            domain: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/mg.a.com/messages',
            // Your API key from mailgun.com
            apiKey: 'key-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
        }
},
```

The server works perfectly (all data is loaded)
Mailgun works perfectly (sending emails from terminal works like a charm)

But when I try to reset password, the following message is displayed in the log:

> 2017-07-17T22:20:06.550173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/requestPasswordReset" host=a.herokuapp.com request_id=ff60cd44-6557-464c-9f17-aaaaaaaaa fwd="12.345.678.90" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=77ms status=200 bytes=483 protocol=https

And nothing happens

What I am doing wrong ?????
If I will remove the appName I will see in the log:

> An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.' } code=1, message=An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.

If I will request reset for wrong user I will see in the log:

> 2017-07-17T22:27:23.340663+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'No user found with email a@gmail.comy.' } code=205, message=No user found with email a@gmail.comy.
>       2017-07-17T22:27:23.349814+00:00 app[web.1]: [object Object]

It means that everything is ok, BUT IT IS NOT SENDING AN EMAIL

Thanks for any response.